# Moving average of time series objects in Array

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

[Using Node and ReactJS]
I need help transforming data within my array of objects into a moving average. This data is constantly updated and holds dates in order.

```
[...{
  x: 2020-02-13T03:31:46.864+00:00
  y: 0.49366917937994004
}...]
```

Need help with an implementation that can transform the data into moving average, while maintaining the structure of the Data.

My main problem is how I could perform the moving average while ensuring that the dates are preserved and used in the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a function that allows you to get moving averages based on different time periods, you first sort the data into chronological order then you get slices of the array based on the interval you want to use (2-day, 3-day, etc..). After that you compute the average of each slice then you put all that into one larger array to give you a bunch of moving averages based on the time period. There are plenty of ways this function can breakdown (bad datetime inputs mainly) so take it with a grain of salt and make sure to implement some testing in advance if possible.

```
const testData =  [
  {
    x: '2020-02-13T03:31:46.864+00:00',
    y: 0.4936691793799400
  },
  {
    x: '2020-02-14T03:31:46.864+00:00',
    y: 0.5936691793799400
  },
  {
    x: '2020-02-01T03:31:46.864+00:00',
    y: 0.1936691793799400
  },
  {
    x: '2020-02-06T03:31:46.864+00:00',
    y: 0.2936691793799400
  },
  {
    x: '2020-02-06T03:32:46.864+00:00',
    y: 0.9936691793799400
  }
]


const sortDates = (data) => data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.x) - new Date (b.x));
const getAverage = (data) => data.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.y, 0) / data.length;

const computeMovingAverage = (data, period) => {
  const movingAverages = [];
  const sortedData = sortDates(data);

  // if the period is greater than the length of the dataset
  // then return the average of the whole dataset
  if (period > sortedData.length) {
    return getAverage(data);
  }
  for (let x = 0; x + period - 1 < sortedData.length; x += 1) {
    console.log('sortedData.slice(x, x + period)', sortedData.slice(x, x + period))
    movingAverages.push(getAverage(sortedData.slice(x, x + period)))
  }
  return movingAverages;
}

const twoDayMovingAverage = computeMovingAverage(testData, 2);
const threeDayMovingAverage = computeMovingAverage(testData, 3);

console.log('twoDayMovingAverage', twoDayMovingAverage);
console.log('threeDayMovingAverage', threeDayMovingAverage);

/*
twoDayMovingAverage [
  0.24366917937994,
  0.6436691793799401,
  0.74366917937994,
  0.54366917937994
]
threeDayMovingAverage [ 0.49366917937994, 0.59366917937994, 0.6936691793799401 ]
*/
```